# python load the value to a variable from a txt file

Tags: python

the txt file is like the following:

```
a.txt
['a','b','c']   #single line txt file
```

What I want to do is, in Python commandline:

```
>> f = open('a.txt','r')
>> a = f.readline()  # want to put the list in to a, same as "a = ['a','b','c']"
```

What should I do?
New to python, can't think of an idea.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

this is assuming you have this in your file..."a b c" :

```
>>f = open('a.txt','r')
>> a = f.readline()  # want to put the list in to a, same as "a = ['a','b','c']"
>>#add this, it splits your input into array
>>a = a.split(" ")
```

this is assuming you have this in your file..."['a','b','c']":
do this

```
>>f = open('a.txt','r')
>> a = f.readline()  # want to put the list in to a, same as "a = ['a','b','c']"
>>#add this, it splits your input into array
>>a = a[1:len(a)-1]
>>a = a.split(",")
```

Comment: this is the right code:
with open("test.txt",'r') as f:
 a = f.read()
b = a.strip()
c = eval(b)
print c